# Pandas if colum contains string then get unique value from another column and drop rows from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a small problem. I have this dataframe with 7 columns.
Two of them are 'IP' and 'URL'.

It is a web log data set, so I am trying to get unique IP of rows, where URL contains string "robots.txt" and then if this condition is applied drop the rows of the uniqueIP's from dataframe.

I had a hard time trying to solve this.
I tried pandas groupby but cant solve it still.
I am able to get unique ip's where url contains string "robots.txt" in this code:

```py
robots = data2[data2.url.str.contains('robots.txt', regex=True)] 
len(robots[['ip']].drop_duplicates())
```

But after that I don't know how to drop these rows from dataframe. Does someone have some tips ? Thanks.

---

Here is the sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6q39.png

---

Dataframe has around 30k rows. So desired output is to drop all rows from dataframe if string "robots.txt" is in url column. I can do that but trick is to remember values from column 'ip' when column 'url' contains that particular string and drop rows that are accessed through that particular ip address

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframe and an example of the desired output

Comment: oh sorry, i answered it below.

Comment: @MichalKis Please add those details by editing your question.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh did that :)

Comment: @MichalKis please add it as text instead of image

Comment: Do you mean you want to drop the row that `url` contains `robots.txt`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh first find rows when 'url' contains string "robots.txt". After that get ip adresses in 'ip' column based on first condition. I also tried to put these addresses in some unique list but did not work. Get unique ip addresses and drop rows accessed from these ip addresses in 'ip' still based on condition of 'url'.

Answer (score 0):

Just negate your condition

```
robots_condition = data2.url.str.contains('robots.txt')
no_crawl_ips = data2.loc[robots_condition, 'ip'].unique()
data2 = data2[~robots_condition]
```

Comment: Yes it works like that i also tried that. But as I said, trick is to get a value from column 'ip' and then drop these rows from unique ip addresses.

Comment: Variable `no_crawl_ips` will have the IPs. Please see the answer. @MichalKis